# How to test if a web page was successfully opened via intent (Robolectric)

Tags: android, robolectric

I wrote the following bit of code to open a url on the phone's browser on a button click

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString))
startActivity(intent)
```

I am trying to write a Robolectric test which will pass only if the desired web page is open, but am not sure how to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to write a Robolectric test which will pass only if the
>   desired web page is open

This is not possible, however (*and this is actually what you should be testing*) you can check *whether* `startActivity` *was called* on your `Context` using an `Intent` *matching certain criteria*.

Provided that you have designed your code to be testable, you should have a method (or class) that takes a `Context` and an `Uri` or `String`. We will assume the following:

```
fun openLink(context: Context, link: Uri){
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, link)
  context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Then we could write the following test (note: this example uses [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)):

```
@Test
fun `verify intent was broadcast`(){
  val context: Context = mock()
  val expectedLink = "https://google.com"
  val uri: Uri = mock()
  whenever(uri.toString()).thenReturn(expectedLink)
  tested.openLink(context, uri) // "tested" is the instance of your class under test
  verify(context).startActivity(
    argThat {
      this.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW &&
          this.dataString!! == expectedLink
      }
    )
  }
```